# example of application who use vaadin

Tags: web-applications, vaadin

I tried to search some application who use "vaadin", excepted "liferay".

I found nothing so i would like to have a better idea how to split an application (design), best practice and so on with this framework.

It seem to be a great framework but it lack of good information about it.

thanks

Comment: There is now a dashboard demo [http://demo.vaadin.com/dashboard](http://demo.vaadin.com/dashboard)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the Vaadin's demo sampler ([found here](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/)) will help you to see what you can do with your component.

For the best practice, I'll recommend you to read the "book of Vaadin" ([found here](http://vaadin.com/fr/book)). This book well describe the concept of Vaadin.

Regards,

Éric

Comment: i see the demo, but it's not really what i search... i would like to have a complete small application to be able to test it

Comment: look at this [page](http://vaadin.com/fr/who-is-using-vaadin) on Vaadin web site.

Answer (score 4):

Vaadin is well suited for *applications*, not *sites*. Which means many companies can use it internally without a lot of publicity.
I'm currently rewriting my Eclipse-based application to have a Vaadin-based web UI, but it's not available for download yet.

Comment: +1 for 'not to websites'

Comment: why cant vaadin be used for building sites e.g ecommerce sites ?

Answer (score 1):

The Magnolia 5.0 uses Vaadin for the User Interface. Its wiki[1] documents the best practice of using Vaadin such as Web Browser History Management aka Back Button,using Model-View-Presenter pattern, etc

You can try download the Magnolia 5.0 development version or build it from the source to see it in action.

[1] http://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/UX/Magnolia+5.0

Answer (score 1):

One of the best posts on the topic I have read are from Philipp Bärfuss of Magnolia, see

1. http://philipp-baerfuss-magnolia.blogspot.com/2010/08/why-vaadin-odyssey.html
2. http://philipp-baerfuss-magnolia.blogspot.com/2010/08/why-vaadin-line-of-argument.html
3. http://philipp-baerfuss-magnolia.blogspot.com/2010/08/why-vaadin-proof-of-concept.html

IIRC Liferay is not really using Vaadin, but they allow you to use Vaadin in your own portlets. Magnolia is betting their future on Vaadin, and if you read the above posts, you'll know why.

From my personal interactions with the Vaadin crew as well as with our own customers, my impression is that Vaadin has momentum.

Answer (score 0):

[this](http://youcaneatat.com) is entirely built using Vaadin just so you can see what is possible, but not much technical information on how they use it yet.

Comment: interesting, seem a litle bit slow

Comment: Yes, it is quite slow. This is because it uses alot of Vaadin add-ons. This is a big thing to watch out for when using Vaadin. If you want super fast page load times then I would NOT recommend Vaadin

Comment: link doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Yes, I "think" company is not going anymore, but I am not 100% sure

Comment: As a side comment I do think Vaadin was the wrong technology is retrospect. Vaadin is very heavy on resources, and is brilliant for intranet applications, but not public facing websites.

Answer (score 0):

Vaadin is used in Activiti Explorer - application for interacting with [Activiti framework](http://www.activiti.org/) (open-source light-weight workflow and Business Process Management (BPM) Platform)
Demo instance (can start with some delays) : http://blog-demo-instance.activiti.cloudbees.net/ for login and password use 'kermit'
Github repository: https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti/tree/master/modules/activiti-explorer